# How to read list of options from web browser - blue prism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to read the values from the redbus website "from" field.
I type 'b' and all the cities starting with b are listed in a drop-down.
I tried to read the values using read stage, get table attribute, but didn't work. I had spied the elements using html mode.
I got an error saying no html table found in get table call
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Sounds like what you're trying to read *isn't* actually a table. Could you share a link or some example code of what you're trying to read?

Answer (score 0):

spy drop-down list after you write the data to it then change the element type to .NET GRID in the application modeller then read it to a collection.